# Facebook like us fields

Tags: facebook, drupal

I want to add a feature on my Drupal site its as follow hope someone can help.

I have a field called link which contains the link to download stuff and it is visible to all.
I want visitor to 1st like us on Facebook and only then the link should be available to see.

I am using Drupsl for Facebook module

Comment: I have not yet entered any code I am a new bee

Answer (score 0):

Like-Buttons are restricted by fb. To realize your project you have to start a request on graph.facebook if the user is likinig your... whatever.